# Link error: undef reference - friend function

Tags: c++, undefined-reference, friend-function

Just the salient details:

**Compilation**:

```
g++ -c memref_test.cpp
g++ -c -I/home/chap/private/WDI/git -I/home/chap/private/WDI/git/include -I/usr/local/mysql/include -I/usr/local/include   -I/home/chap/private/WDI/git -I/home/chap/private/WDI/git/include -I/usr/include/mysql -fno-strict-aliasing  -g -O0 --std=c++11  MemRef.cpp
g++ -o memref_test memref_test.o MemRef.o
```

**Error**:

```
MemRef.h:36:24: warning: inline function ‘bool operator<(const MemRef&, const MemRef&)’ used but never defined [enabled by default]

/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_algo.h:86: undefined reference to `operator<(MemRef const&, MemRef const&)'
```

**MemRef.h**:

```
class MemRef {
    public:
        friend inline bool operator< (const MemRef& lhs, const MemRef& rhs);
};
```

**MemRef.cpp**:

```
inline bool 
operator< (const MemRef& lhs, const MemRef& rhs){
    int minlen = 
        lhs._len <= rhs._len 
        ? lhs._len 
        : rhs._len;
    int res = memcmp(lhs._ptr, rhs._ptr, minlen);
    if (res < 0) return true;
    if (res > 0) return false;
    // equal for minlen, so he with the lesser length wins
    return (lhs._len < rhs._len);
}
```

**memref_test.cpp**:

```
deque<MemRef> memrefs;
const string record("Record 1\tABLE\tBAKER\tCHARLIE");
MemRef::split(memrefs, record, '\t');
std::sort(memrefs.begin(), memrefs.end());
```

I've racked my brain for six hours, googling and searching SO, and I need help. Thanks.

Comment: Remove the `inline` from the operator *and* friend decl or move the whole thing to your header file.

Comment: I did a little searching for 'inline' http://stackoverflow.com/q/1759300/522385 and decided to just remove the keyword.  Worked.